# Polynomial Integration from Arbitrary Points

Tags: integration, polynomials

I've got a set of equally sampled points (audio), which I'm needing to calculate;

> The power, the mean square of the filtered input signal in a measurement interval T is measured as:
>
> $ z_i = \frac{1}{T} \int_{0}^T y_i^2 dt$
>
> where $y_i$ is the input signal (filtered by the 2-stage pre-filter as described above, and i ∈ I where I = {L,R,C,Ls,Rs}, the set of input channels.

([See original snippet here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEHm5.png))

Can't seem to get my head around the bit about the integral of the signal^2.

Looks like I need to derive a function from arbitrary points to solve this(?);
A simple cumulative square-plus-triangle integration isn't beyond me, however, deriving a polynomial function from variable points is.

Any pointers towards;

1. if my reading of the method is correct? (I have a feeling it might just be another way of denoting RMS)
2. how to go about deriving a function from a set of points.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please try to learn $\LaTeX$ from https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: updated to reflect